# Error in autowiring a @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) object

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I am trying to implement connection to service providers using spring social communication controllers as described in [Spring Social reference doc here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html).

When initializing, the following service can not find the currentUser bean. I get the exception

```
 `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dynamease.serviceproviders.user.User com.dynamease.serviceproviders.SPResolver.currentUser; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.dynamease.serviceproviders.user.User] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This happens when initializing the following service :

```
@Service
public class SPResolver {

public SPResolver() {
}

@Autowired
private User currentUser;

@Autowired
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

 public void connectUser(String id) {
 currentUser.setId(id);
     }

public void disconnectUser() {
    this.currentUser = null;
}
```

And here is the configuration relevant configuration file part

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public User currentUser() {
    return new User(null);
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
    String id = currentUser().getId();
    if (id == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
    }
    return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(id);
}
```

I suspect that useing a "new User" for the bean definition might be the cause and the reason why in the spring sample they use static SecurityContext classes with user info encapsulated inside a threadlocal but did not find in the doc any convincing information about it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios answer and comments exchange, I read more carefully section 5.5 and 9.6 of Spring reference documentation and found out the problem :

It is ok to have singleton `@Service` (in my case the `SPResolver`) referencing session or request scoped beans if you ensure :

1. that you use some kind of AOP proxy mechanism so that when the @Service is created initially and the scoped beans does not exist, a proxy is created that will then reference correctly the scoped beans during program execution. That is what I was actually doing in my initial code thru the `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` line in the currentUser bean creation.
2. The scoped beans needs to be referenced in the `@Service` thru an interface and not directly with a Java Class, which I was not doing for the `User` class. Actually, the copy-paste example I took for the ConnectionRepository Bean was working as ConnectionRepository is an Interface.

Here is the working configuration class code :

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public CurrentUserContext currentUser() {
    return new CurrentUserContextImpl();
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
    String id = currentUser().getId();
    if (id == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
    }
    return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(id);
}
```

and the @Service declarations :

```
@Service
public class SPResolver {

public SPResolver() {
}

@Autowired
private CurrentUserContext currentUser;

@Autowired
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;
```

Comment: Instead of using interface one can use `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`

Answer (score 1):

Your `SPResolver` class is a `@Service` with default singleton scope. As such, it will be initialized at startup.

Your `User` bean is `request` scope so a new instance can be created for each request.

However, at startup, there is no such request and therefore a `User` bean cannot be injected, because it does not exist.

---

That may not be the root cause here. It seems more likely that you're not scanning the right configs, but you will get the above problem eventually.

Comment: I thought the Proxy part of the scope annotation was actually meant to deal with this issue...

Comment: @Yves What do you think it's supposed to proxy? There hasn't been a request yet.

Comment: @Yves Please read through [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other).