# Scoped Bean not available for injection

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, scope

@Scope stopping injection of class

I have the following class:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("delegator")
@Scope(value = "simpleThreadScope", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class AsyncDelegator implements IAsyncDelegator {
    ....
}
```

Which is being used in the following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class C2GWebController extends AbstractDeferredResultController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegator")
    IAsyncDelegator delegator;

    ....
}
```

However, when this is run on our dev machine, it gives the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.async.IAsyncDelegator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=delegator)}
```

even though the beans are being scanned with the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.AUTODETECT)
@ComponentScan("com.company")
@EnableAsync
@RequestMapping
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config implements BeanFactoryAware {
    ....
}
```

Dev machine is:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Server built:  Aug 4 2014 03:06:35
Server number:  7.0.42.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:    3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Architecture:  amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_65-mockbuild_2014_07_14_06_04-b00
JVM Vendor:    Oracle Corporation
```

This is running CentOS 7

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924824/error-in-autowiring-a-scopevalue-request-proxymode-scopedproxymode-inte) but the class is being referenced in the controller through the interface.  I would suggest that it was due to the OS configuration, but this is an identical configuration that is being deployed to several machines (Through Chef/Vagrant).

There appears to be something in the software which is not being specified which is causing this not to work, but I can't work out what it is.

This code works for OSX (Mavericks) and various Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Is your `@Configuration` class loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`? Why is it annotated with `@RequestMapping`? Do you have something to handle your custom scope?

Comment: Full stack trace here : http://pastebin.com/yzc6nrGu

Comment: I think it should be `@Component("delegator")` and not `@Qualifier` for `AsyncDelegator` bean.